# Is there proof that All Might was recognized as "the greatest hero in the world", in spite of the japan only ranking, or is it just fan speculation?

Tags: my-hero-academia

During the My Hero Academia anime series, I had the sensation that All Might was shown as the greatest hero in the world. However, I dont remember any statement saying it, perhaps there is, but I dont remember. And recently (or a couple of years ago) is have been clarified in the manga and in the movie, that the hero rankings we see in the anime/manga are only for Japan, meaning All Might and Endeavor were only recognized by those rankings to be the greatest heroes of Japan.

However, the My Hero Academia wikia states:

> All Might was recognized as the greatest hero in the world

[Toshinori Yagi](https://myheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Toshinori_Yagi)

Is there any proof that All Might was recognized as "the greatest hero in the world" (unofficially I suppose, but by popular acclamation, inside the story), even though the hero ranking was only for Japan, or is it just fan speculation?

Comment: There's a footnote on that sentence that refers to [manga chapter 95](https://myheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_95) mentioning "No. 1 Hero", but it seems it's unclear if this refers to "... in the world" or "... in Japan".

Comment: @AkiTanaka I'm reading it now, after your comment. The only thing I see is a mention to him being number one, but it doesnt say number one in the world or number one in Japan

Comment: Shoto Todoroki thinking: "if All Might really can no longer stand at the front lines.. then the position  of number one.."

Comment: I think you're right that there's nothing explicitly ranking his strength against global heroes. There is a lot of behavior that indicates his global popularity - The [Two Heroes](https://myheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/My_Hero_Academia:_Two_Heroes) movie says his dream was to become the world's Symbol of Peace and he was the leader of the international task force in [World Heroes' Mission](https://myheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/My_Hero_Academia:_World_Heroes%27_Mission) - but even at his prime we currently don't know if there was someone better.

Comment: Additionally, All For One is referred to as Japan's most powerful villain, not the world's. Though the latest arc has shown that his influence extends worldwide, if they haven't called him out as the world's most powerful then it seems to be intentional. Maybe to leave room for future characters and arcs?

Comment: To me it feels like that they started with the idea of All Might and the japanese heroes being the most powerful, and later they nerfed them to expand the story, but I have no evidence

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Stars and Stripes, USA's (referred to as the homeland of superheroes, might or might not be an indication of it being very high in the world ranking) Number 1 hero, looks at All Might with admiration. So it could be argued that All Might in his best era would rank above her.

Comment: @paulnamida but supposing mutations or whatever makes people have quirks are distributed evenly around the world, there is no reason to think US would have the people with the most powerful quirks. If heroes would be like Ironman or Batman or Captain America, where they are artificially created, we could assume US would be one of the countries with the most powerful heroes, but this isnt the case